# Using Azure Active Directory Interactive when authenticating from Azure Functions to Azure SQL DB

Tags: .net, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-sdk, azure-managed-identity

I'm trying to authenticate access from an Azure function to Azure SQL DB using am Azure Active Directory managed identity and the Active Directory Interactive .  I've successfully used the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi when trying to authenticate from an app service to Azure SQL DB, but in that case I can set up the authentication provider declaratively in the Web.config file.  There seems to be no Web.config file for Azure Functions.  How can I programmatically do the same thing as was done declaratively in the Web.config file for Azure Functions? Or is there a simpler approach to use here? I'm trying to avoid embedding secrets or using Key Value to store secrets, and I want a solution where I can still debug Azure Functions locally in Visual Studio, much as I can for app services.

Thanks,
--Bonnie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

> How can I programmatically do the same thing as was done declaratively
>   in the Web.config file for Azure Functions? Or is there a simpler
>   approach to use here?

---

According to my test, if we want to use Azure MSI to connect Azure SQL in Azure function, please refer to the following steps:

1. [Create function app project in VS2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs)
2. Configure local.setting.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<your storage connection string>",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SQLConnectionString": "Server=tcp:<server name>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=<db name>;"
  }

}
```

2. [Configure MSI for VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication#local-development-authentication)

   a. Sign in to Visual Studio and use `Tools` > `Options` to open Options.

   b. Select `Azure Service Authentication`, enter your Azure SQL admin account  and select OK.
3. develop the function
   For example

```
/* please install sdk :
   Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication -Version 1.3.1
   Install-Package  System.Data.SqlClient -Version 4.6.1

*/
[FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            string str = "SQLConnectionString";
            string conStr = GetSqlAzureConnectionString(str);
            var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
            string accessToken = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/");

            var conn = new SqlConnection(conStr);
            conn.AccessToken = accessToken;
            string result = "";
            var sql = "select * from StarWars where episode=1";
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    while (reader.Read()) {

                        result = reader.GetString(2);
                    }
                }
            }
            return new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {result}");

        }

        private static string GetSqlAzureConnectionString(string SQLConnectionString)
        {
            string conStr = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable($"ConnectionStrings:{SQLConnectionString}", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(conStr)) // Azure Functions App Service naming convention
                conStr = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable($"SQLAZURECONNSTR_{SQLConnectionString}", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
            return conStr;
        }
```

4. Debug the function with Visual Studio. Please note that we need to install [Azure Functions Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#core-tools-versions) before our debug it.

Besides, If you want to publish it after you debug, please refer to the following steps

1. Create an Azure Function
2. [Configure MSI for function app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?context=azure%2Factive-directory%2Fmanaged-identities-azure-resources%2Fcontext%2Fmsi-context&tabs=dotnet#adding-a-system-assigned-identity)
   [image]
   [image]
3. Configure Azure SQL

   a. [Use your Azure Sql AD admin to connect Azure SQL vai SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure?tabs=azure-powershell)

   b. Add the MSI to the database you need use

   ```
   USE [<db name>]
   GO
   create user [<function app name>] from external provider
   ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER [<function app name>]
   ```
4. Add your connection string in Azure Function app application settings
   [image]
   [image]
5. [Publish it with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs#publish-to-azure)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response.  I came up with a similar approach.